# how to run tsql from a remote system in command prompt

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, command-prompt

I wanted to know how to run a TSQL statement from a remote system by connecting to the other system and run a TSQL statement through command prompt.

I have tried the following code but this code doesnt run on the other system.

PS: other system doesnt have sql server installed so it is compulsory that we use just command prompt to run from that system.

```
sqlcmd -S 100,1433\MSSQLSERVER -U sa -P abc -i C:\table.sql -o C:\output.txt
```

Comment: What is `100`? Also do you think it is expecting C:\ on your desktop or C:\ on the server?

Comment: You could install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack.

Comment: 100 is my computer name c:\ is in the other system where sql statement is present and i need to run that file

Comment: we are not allowed to install any sql related stuff on the other system we just need to run a command in command prompt

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run tsql from a remote system in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977603/how-to-run-tsql-from-a-remote-system-in-command-prompt)

Comment: doesn't run? Does the command line return any messages or does it appear to run?

Answer (score -1):

[SQL Server 2000 - osql Utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

There's file called **OSQL.exe** which I am using for this job.
File comes from SQL Server 2000 (52 KB).
You can run it in CMD with simmiliar arguments to sqlcommand.
Remember to use GO after each batch

Example

```
Select * from Sales [enter]
GO [enter]
```